# Submitting the form by choosing calendar date without submit button PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, calendar

I just would like to know if it is possible to submit a form simply by selecting a date in the calendar without clicking on the submit button? I also wanted to ask if it is possible to choose today's date when you open the page? My code is below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) $name = $_POST['name'];
else $name = "(Not typed)";
echo <<<_END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="1.php">
        Choose date for result showing :
        <input type="date" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        </body>
</html>
_END;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type='date' name='name' onchange='this.form.submit()' >
```

add this onchange event, it will submit your form when this input type changes, I hope it helps